# nginx and nginx-prometheus-exporter

Tags: nginx, prometheus, nginx-config

We have a use case where :

1. in the nginx:1.24.0 container, we added below lines for enabling mTLS ability, so, without passing mTLS, we encounter HTTP  400 error `No required SSL certificate was sent`

```
       listen 8081 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/tls.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/tls.key;
        ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/root-ca/bundle.pem;
        ssl_verify_client on;
```

2. Now, we want to export the metrics to prometheus using nginx-prometheus-exporter using this below instruction https://medium.com/@parthyadav3105/quick-reference-for-collecting-nginx-metrics-using-prometheus-9cf6592bab93

However, in the nginx conf, we add "/metrics" endpoint for metrics, how can nginx-prometheus-metrics access nginx to retrieve metrics (reason  required ssl_client_certificate)? How do we achieve this ? Is there  a way that nginx-prometheus-metrics can access metrics endpoint in nginx with certificate passed ?

Comment: I believe you need `-nginx.ssl-client-cert` and `-nginx.ssl-client-key` [command line parameters](https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-prometheus-exporter#command-line-arguments) passed to your nginx-prometheus-metrics.

Comment: Also, I believe this question is off topic on SO. Please choose one of [su], [sf] or [devops.se] and flag your question for moderators to move it there. (Or if you'll not receive any downvotes before you see this message - just delete it here, and re-ask on more appropriate site)